# vs 2013 mvc localdb - no access to option

Tags: asp.net-mvc, localdb

I have a problem with **localdb**. When I open context menu I see only Refresh, Copy and Properties. I can't open a table, why?

Comment: Are you accessing it through the Server Explorer or View -> Sql Server Object Explorer ?

Comment: in the Server Explorer http://i.imgur.com/0KHuMeM.png